# Where is Boundedness Used?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

> A sequence $(f_n)$ of bounded functions on $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ converges uniformly to $f$ if and only if $||f_n - f||_A \to 0$.

I was working the through the proof of the above theorem when I noticed, as it appeared to me, that the boundedness assumption was never explicitly invoked. My question is, exactly where is this assumption used? I give a screenshot of the proof below:

[image]

EDIT:

The norm $||\cdot||_A$ is defined as $||f||_A := \sup \{|f(x)| ~|~ x \in A\}$, where $f$ is some function from $A$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: But, what is (7) and what is $\lVert \cdot\rVert_A$?

Comment: @ClementC. The A-norm is perhaps the sup-norm used in the context of uniform convergence - but the OP will need to provide details.

Comment: If this is what I assume and what @SeanRoberson writes, then you need the boundnedness in order to even write $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_A$. If $g$ is not bounded, you can't even *write* $\lVert g\rVert_A$, it is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, without boundedness you can have that $|| g||_A = \infty$, which is generally not allowed for norms.

Comment: The little things you never thought about...

Comment: @ClementC. But how do I know that $f$ doesn't sufficiently 'tame' $f_n$ in $||f - f_n||$, so that it is always finite? If that's the case, then the $f_n$ could be unbounded but $||f_n -f||$ would be finite. I guess that is at the heart of my question: why can't such a scenario be realized?

Comment: You're now asking a different question. The first question is: "where was the boundedness assumption used?" (answer: to write the supremum norm, which you cannot do otherwise, at least without an argument as to why it's OK). The new one is "Is this assumption necessary?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple. Usually you would choose a sequence of continuous functions and $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ might be compact. Then you can define the seminorm $\Vert f \Vert_A = \max_{x \in A} \vert f(x) \vert$ without any doubt since continuous functions have a maximum on a compact sets. In your case none such properties are given. So if you want to define the seminorm $\Vert f \Vert_A = \sup_{x \in A} \vert f(x) \vert$ you need to make sure that it is well defined, i.e. $\Vert f \Vert_A \neq \infty$. The most simple way to do that is to demand that your sequence is bounded on $A$. In this case the seminorm is always well-defined and you can use it in your proof :)